# What's the best way to rewrite this generic function I wrote in C++ in C?

Tags: c++, c

```
//Prints out a given array 
template <typename T>
void print(T t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << t[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I have an idea but it includes passing the size of the array. Is it possible to avoid this?

*Update
Thanks for all of the answers/ideas but this problem is getting way deeper than my snorkeler can handle. I wanted to rewrite my C++ code in C because it was horribly written and slow. I see now that I have an opportunity to make it even worse in C. I'll rewrite it from the ground up in Python(performance be damned). Thanks again

Comment: Actually, that should be `typename T::size_type`, not `int`. (Oh, and you can pass an array so that the size carries over implicitly - in C++.)

Comment: We need more. You've used `.size()` which implies `std::array`, which of course does not exist in C.

Comment: you can't. C doesn't have anything like templates. You have to write one or more functions that do what you need for your specific use cases. You can't write a C function that prints out anything that has an size() function in C.

Comment: if you wanted to use horrible horrible style you could just make the parameter a void pointer.

Comment: well I guess I meant container objects... I'm quite new to C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have ELEMENTS, it's

```
#define ELEMENTS(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))
```

Then,

```
#define print_array(a, specifier) print_array_impl(a, specifier, ELEMENTS(a), sizeof(*a))

void print_array_impl(void* a, char* specifier, size_t asize, size_t elsize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < asize; i++)
    {
        // corrected based on comment -- unfortunately, not as general
        if (strcmp(specifier, "%d") == 0)
           printf(specifier, ((int*)a)[i]); 
        // else if ... // check other specifiers
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Use like this

```
print_array(a, "%d") // if a is a int[]
```

and, `a` needs to be an array name, not a pointer (or else ELEMENTS won't work)

Comment: you can call print_array_impl if you malloced.

Comment: So if I had an array of pointers to strict objects and those  objects contanied  employee names Could I just print out all the names using this method?

Comment: There is no printf specification for your struct.  You need to provide a way to print.

Comment: Ah I see thanks..even though I won't use C for this project this is good knowledge to have for future reference

Comment: Wouldn't that print the address (or a part of it) of the array element instead of the actual value? To `printf()` `int`s are passed by value not by reference.

Comment: yes this code is incorrect. If you pass an int[] what will be printed is the memory location of the index of the int you want. Notice how there is no dereference occuring in the code.

Comment: Sorry -- thanks for pointing that out.  I put in a correction -- unfortunately, the code can't easily be generalized.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know what is the size of an array without passing the size of that array (except operating with `sizeof` in static arrays). This is because the a pointer to a block of memory will only point to the base of the block of memory, from which you can know where the array/block of memory starts, but as there is no end defined you cannot determine where it will end.

- You either need to set your own length per array and preserve it, and use it with the array like as described:

  - You can make a new type like:

  ```
  struct _my_array {
     typename arr[MAX];
     int n;
  } my_array;
  ```

  OR

  ```
  struct _my_array {
     typename *arr;
     int n;
  } my_array;
  ```

  In this case you need to allocate the a block of memory dynamically with `new` or `malloc` , and when finished free the memory with `delete` or `free` (respectively).

  - Or you can simply pass the array number of elements through the function.
- Another way is to use a special terminator value of your array type which if encountered will be determined as the end of the array. In this case you need not preserve the size. For example a string is `'\0'` terminated, so all the string functions know that when a `'\0'` character is encounter in the `char` array it will consider that the string has end.

**UPDATE**

Because this is a generic function and the array can be of any type, one thing which you can do is like this:

```
struct _my_generic_arr {
  void *arr;
  int n;
  int type;
} my_generic_arr;
```

When populating this array you can use any type. To identify which type, pass an identified in the `type` component. Each unique value will determine which type does the `arr` pointer actually points to (was actually the intended type to be pointed). The `n` will define the length. Now, depending on different values of `type` make a `switch - case` or an `if - else` ladder or nest, and process the array as you need.

Comment: That's not strictly true. `sizeof` works fine on any array, but arrays passed as function parameters turn into pointers. So C is misleading you when it lets you declare a function `void fun(char arr[12])`. The upshot is that arrays allocated on the stack are okay to pass to `sizeof` as long as it was *this* stack frame.

Comment: @nmichaels: i agree, because the memory is typecasted to `char []` type, operating on which `sizeof` will return the value of the cast. I have just mentioned this point in the beginning.

Comment: actually, you cant make that garuntee. I just tried doing sizeof on a parameter declared as char tt[12] and I get 4 (= sizeof(char*))

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible in c to track the size of an array in other block,,
It would be a better option to pass the size of the array along..

The other option would be to declare a global variable that has the size and using that variable inside the function
Eg,,

```
int size=<some value>
void main()
{
int arr[<same value>];
}
void print(T t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       printf("%d ",t[i])   //assuming T as int
    }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, you would need to pass two additional parameters: the size of the array (as you mentioned), and some way of indicating how to convert t[i] into a string.  To convert t[i] to a string, you could create a custom switch statement to decode possible types, pass a pointer to a function that will return the string pointer, or you could pass the printf format specifier (e.g. "%d" for integer).

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct {
    void *array;
    size_t length;
    int element_width;
    printer_t to_string;
} container;
```

`printer_t` is a type that describes a function pointer that takes an element pointer and returns a string (or prints it, if you don't want to `free` the string). This is almost never worth doing in C. That doesn't mean it can't be done. I would emphasize, though, that none of this is intended to imply that it *should* be done.

The function itself would look something like this:

```
void print(container *thing)
{
    size_t offset;
    int width;
    char *stringified;

    width = thing->element_width;
    for (offset = 0; offset * width < thing->length; offset += width)
    {
        stringified = thing->to_string(thing->array + offset);
        printf("%s ", stringified);
        free(stringified);
    }
}
```

What this does is essentially turn a struct into a faux class with a function pointer for a method. You could be more object-oriented and put the method in the type being printed and make it an array of those instead. Either way, it's not a good idea. C is for writing C. If you try to write in a different language, you'll end up with all sorts of terrible stuff like this.

Comment: I dont think it was so much of writing in a different language but implementing a concept(a function that takes an array of any type/size as an argument and prints out its elements) I see now that it's much more involved than I've ever imagined though

Answer (score 1):

The problem is larger than you think. If you have an array of size 12, how do you know what data is held in that array? It could be 3 char*'s (on 32 bit system), 3 int32_t's, or even 12 chars. You have no way of knowing how to interpret the data. The best you could do is to implement your own version of a v-table and putting a print or toString function into it.