# Template in ansi C?

Tags: c, templates

How I can create function with other types of data (some struct or sth)? In C++ exist templates, but in C?

I hear about void *, but i dont know if it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to rewrite this generic function I wrote in C++ in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287086/whats-the-best-way-to-rewrite-this-generic-function-i-wrote-in-c-in-c)

Comment: Yes, a `void*` is just a generic pointer, so you can use it if you want to (for example) write a generic data structure that takes pointers to arbitrary already-allocated structures. But I'm not clear on exactly what your use case is. Can you edit your question to describe what you are trying to do in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the way to do it *is* with `void *`. You might also need use function pointers, for example if you need to compare generic values.

The other way to do it is to use [xmacros](http://blog.brush.co.nz/2009/08/xmacros/), but that's generally more for reducing code duplication for very similar structures.

Answer (score -1):

`void *` is the solution in C as any pointer has the same `sizeof()` as `void *`. Of course, you get no type safety, but it's as good an abstraction as you can get with C. Furthermore, you could look at `stdarg.h` and variadic functions, but again, you should keep track yourself of what you're doing, since the compiler won't aid you one bit.

Comment: It's not actually always true that "any pointer has the same `sizeof()` as `void *`"; word pointers and byte pointers can have different sizes, as can function pointers and object pointers. It's more correct to say that "any object pointer can safely be converted to `void *` and back".

Comment: Nicely noticed. Speaking of which, look what I'm doing at http://elf.cs.pub.ro/so/wiki/laboratoare/resurse/injections#casting-pointers-to-class-functions-to-void and cringe! :)